# How to evaluate a string and keep precision in Python

Tags: python, floating-point, precision

I’m trying to get a more precise result from this code:

```
a = str(10**20+10**-20)
b = eval(a)
```

I want to obtain around 42 decimal places so Python doesn’t round it to 1e+20.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limiting floats to two decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)

Answer (score 1):

You actually 'only' need 41 to accomplish that. Use the `decimal` module:

```
import decimal
decimal.getcontext().prec=41
a = 10**20+10**decimal.Decimal(-20)
```

Python's floating-point types are just as inaccurate as in any other language. The `decimal` module contains the `Decimal` data structure, capable of handling arbitrarily long decimal numbers instead. You can read more about it here: [check it out](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/decimal.html).

Comment: Your comment on my post is correct. I removed it to deter potential confusion and upvoted yours.